how do I pass an arbitrary option to the C compiler when installing python packages using pip?
How do I pass an arbitrary option to the C compiler when installing python packages using pip?
I tried, in requirements.txt, the following:
sip --config-settings="--build-option=-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types"

However the compilation of the sip package still croaks due to a -Wincompatible-pointer-types warning (and because presumably -Werror is enabled).
